# Separate Settings in Universal iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults, universal

I'm working on an universal iOS app, but a few user settings don't make as much sense on the iPad.

Can I specify a separate Settings.bundle or Root.plist for use on the iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from 4.0 on you will be able to just rename the file for ipad to contain ~ipad in name and ~iphoone for the iphone ones, for now you can only rename the iphone one and have 3.2 on ipad load the regular named ones.

Comment: The Settings.bundle is not loaded from code.  It's just placed in the app bundle.  So, unfortunately, using UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is not an option.


The device-specific suffixes don't seem to work for the Settings.bundle either.  At least "Settings~iphone.bundle" is being ignored on iOS 4.0.

Comment: hmm how about renaming the individual files in the bundle ? did you try that ?

Comment: Good catch.  This can make a very clean solution, since Root~iphone.plist works on iOS 4.0 and the iPad will use Root.plist on iOS 3.2... Unfortunately I have to be compatible with 3.1.3.  So I'll probably have to wait for 4.0 on the iPad.