# Settings.bundle for iPad only?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, settings

I have a situation where I need one setting to made available for my application via the settings app. My application is universal but this particular setting only makes sense on the iPad so I only want my application to show up in settings on the iPad. Is this possible? I haven't found a way to do it and have tried the following:

1) Renaming the Settings.bundle to Settings~ipad.bundle. My app does not show up in Settings on either device. I believe it must be named Settings.bundle.

2) Rename Root.plist to Root~ipad.plist. On the iPhone the Settings entry for my app still exists but there are no settings available. I don't want the entry to be there.

3) I tried deleting the Settings.bundle if it exists and I am on the iPhone when my app launches the first time, but Settings.bundle is readonly.

Comment: May i know IOS version of your app. This post here discusses about the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277034/separate-settings-in-universal-ios-app

Comment: @Deepesh iOS 5.0+, I have tried the fixes described in the question, which did not seem to work for me, see 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old one, but I want to share my experiences on this.

I managed to create a setting for iPhone only in my app by creating another Root.plist file and naming that to Root~iphone.plist. That way the iPad version of the app reads the Root.plist and iPhone version the Root~iphone.plist.

Hope this helps anyone stumbling on this issue.